# Determinar a página onde o arquivo *.pdf será aberto no browser

Tags: java, pdf, servlet

Tenho um código para exibir um arquivo pdf:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/teste"})
public class abrirPDF extends HttpServlet {

    byte[] arquivo = null;
    File file = new File("C:\\testes\\teste.pdf");

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            arquivo = fileToByte(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(arquivo.length);
        ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ouputStream.write(arquivo, 0, arquivo.length);
        ouputStream.flush();
        ouputStream.close();
    }

    public static InputStream byteToInputStream(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        return bais;
    }

    public static byte[] fileToByte(File imagem) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imagem);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Preciso abrir esse pdf em uma página específica. Isso é, quero que o navegador abra o PDF diretamente em um determinada página e não na primeira página do arquivo. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Oi @AnthonyAccioly tudo bem? É que com esse código meu pdf abre normalmente no browser porém sempre na primeira página do arquivo, e eu preciso poder determinar a página que esse arquivo será aberto.

Comment: Hum... Você já tentou colocar `#page=NumeroDaPagina` no request? Funciona com arquivos pdf servidod diretamente. Dê uma olhada em: [*Acrobat / 
Create a URL to open a PDF file at a specific page*](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html). Se funcionar me dê um toque e transformo em resposta.

Comment: @R.Santos você tem alterado a pergunta conforme respostas vão sendo colocadas. E pior, a pergunta editada está invalidando as respostas dadas. Aqui não é um fórum. É uma site de perguntas e respostas. Você faz uma pergunta bem pensada e formulada, com um problema específico, bem definido, e obtém respostas para ele. Se não for satisfatório, pode fazer novas perguntas, mas não pode ficar alterando a existente de forma a invalidar as respostas. Se precisa alterar demais a pergunta é porque a pergunta não está boa e precisa pensar mais antes postar uma pergunta.Espero que compreenda.Veja o [tour]

Comment: Eu entendo sim @bigown e concordo plenamente, sei que o que está errado. Anthony me explicou isso também. Peço desculpa por ter feito alterações desnecessárias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Meu comentário original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148043/determinar-a-p%c3%a1gina-onde-o-arquivo-pdf-ser%c3%a1-aberto-no-browser#comment306130_148043), a [resposta do José](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148382/100) e [a resposta do Cleidimar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148369/100) mostram a maneira de apontar uma página do lado cliente. Ou seja, fazer com o que o leitor de PDF abra o documento em uma página específica.

Outra solução possível é "recortar" o pdf do lado servidor e enviar somente a página que você necessita. Para fazer isso será necessário usar uma biblioteca própria para manipulação de PDF como a [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Assumindo que você vai passar o número da página como parâmetro para o Servlet (e.g., chamar `teste?numeroPagina=10`) eis um exemplo de como "recortar" o PDF e retornar apenas uma página como resposta:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    File pdfOriginal = new File("C:\\testes\\teste.pdf");

    PDDocument documentoOriginal = null; 
    PDDocument documentoModificado = null;

    // No código real leia o parâmetro de maneira mais robusta
    int numeroPagina = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numeroPagina"));

    try {
        documentoOriginal = PDDocument.load(pdfOriginal);
        // cria documento apenas com a pagina requisitada
        documentoModificado = new PDDocument();
        documentoModificado.addPage(documentoOriginal.getPage(numeroPagina));

        // escreve o documento na resposta
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(pdfOriginal.length());
        documentoModificado.save(response.getOutputStream());  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (documentoOriginal != null) {
            documentoOriginal.close();
        }
        if (documentoModificado != null) {
            documentoModificado.close();
        }
        // você pode também fazer flush e fechar a stream da resposta
        // mas isso não é necessário
    }
}
```

As duas abordagens tem vantagens e desvantagens:

Em termos de usabilidade, a primeira solução serve o arquivo inteiro (deixa o cliente visualizar outras páginas), enquanto a segunda serve apenas a página que você quer exibir.

Do ponto de vista de *performance*, apontar a página do lado do cliente significa que não haverá nenhum processamento mais pesado do lado servidor, ficando seu *Servlet* limitado a capacidade de I/O. Por outro lado você continua transmitindo o PDF inteiro, o que consome mais banda e potencialmente faz com que o documento tome bem mais tempo para ser carregado.

Recortar o PDF do lado do servidor significa processamento mais complexo e sujeito a falhas (a estrutura do arquivo PDF pdf original pode estar "corrompida" ou esse pode ser potencialmente um PDF protegido / criptografado). Em cima do tempo de I/O você também gastará um pouco de CPU nessa brincadeira. Por outro lado o cliente receberá uma única página, o que gasta menos banda e potencialmente significa menor tempo de carregamento.

Se determinada página for ser chamada várias vezes talvez seja melhor dividir o PDF por página e salvar tudo em disco. No fim temos aqui diversas trocas possíveis entre banda, disco e CPU, dependendo da sua aplicação uma ou outra estratégia pode ser melhor.

---

**Fonte**: [Soen - Reading a particular page from a PDF document using PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6839787/664577)

Comment: Certo @AnthonyAccioly, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar o argumento `#page=[numPag]` no Header do Response. Segue o exemplo da página 2 abaixo:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"teste.pdf#page=2\";");
```

[Create a URL to open a PDF file at a specific page](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma maneira de você fazer usando `page` usando este parâmetro `#page=[pagina específica]`,  então ficaria assim caso o arquivo estiver em um endereço específico local:

```
file:///C:/meuarquivo.pdf#page=3
```

Caso esteja na web:

```
http://www.meusite.meuarquivo.pdf#page=3
```

Comment: Dá erro assim, ele não encontra o caminho se colocado dessa maneira que tu sugeriu;

Comment: @R.Santos Tente colocar ali no seu `response` algo do tipo `setParameter`  e coloque `page`  como parâmetro e o número da página.

Comment: @R.Santos ai ficaria assim `response.setParameter("#page", 3)`

Comment: @R.Santos na verdade cara, dê uma modificada ali no seu `service`, acescentando `HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("#page",3);` assim, você estaria setando uma atributo na sua requisição. Ai sim tem que daria certo.